# Do I have to change my Apple Push Notification settings if I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I received this email from Apple:

> The HTTP/2‑based Apple Push Notification service (APNs) provider API lets you take advantage of great features, such as authentication with a JSON Web Token, improved error messaging, and per‑notification feedback. If you still send push notifications with the legacy binary protocol, make sure to upgrade to the APNs provider API as soon as possible. APNs will no longer support the legacy binary protocol after March 31, 2021.

To send push notifications to my app I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Do I have to change my Push Notification settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Firebase FAQs](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#fcm-apns-http2), there should be no action required on your part.

> **Cloud Messaging: Apple announced they're deprecating the legacy binary protocol for APNs. Do I need to do anything?**
> No. Firebase Cloud Messaging switched to the HTTP/2-based APNs protocol in 2017. If you are using FCM to send notifications to iOS devices, there should be no action required on your part.